# Replace text in HTML using Classic ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic, replace

I'm not sure if this is even possible with Classic ASP (VBscript) but what I want to do is the following:

Search for a specific string in a HTML-text (only between p-tags, div-tags, li-tags, span-tags and ignore texts between other tags like a-tags) and replace it with something else. For example:

**The original HTML**

```
<p>Some text with the keyword.</p>
```

**Classic ASP Function**

Search for the keyword in the HTML text only between all p-tags, div-tags, span-tags and li-tags but ignore texts between other tags like a-tags. Replace the keyword with something else.

**The output HTML**

```
<p>Some text with the <a href="someurl">keyword</a>.</p>
```

If this is **not** possible, is there any other way to do this?
Anyone having experience with this?

Just to be clear. The "Some text with the keyword."-text isn't comming from a database because that would be too easy :) It's in the HTML of an .asp-file unfortunately.

Comment: Wow... Nice question. Can you add PHP also in the same question. Would like to do in PHP. `:)`

Comment: This is consierably complex - you're writing a parser. This is a bit overly broad for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: You should be able to do that using regular expressions.
A reference of the VBScript RegExp object and the supported syntax is here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation is required here.. as I was never really into Regular Expressions I came long ago with bunch of my own methods to manipulate text in various ways. Pretty ugly, not best efficiency, but it works.

First of all, add those functions to your code:

```vbs
Function GetBetween(str, leftDelimeter, rightDelimeter)
    Dim tmpArr, result(), x
    tmpArr=Split(str, leftDelimeter)
    If UBound(tmpArr) < 1 Then
        GetBetween=Array() : Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim result(UBound(tmpArr)-1)
    For x=1 To UBound(tmpArr)
        result(x-1)=(Split(tmpArr(x), rightDelimeter))(0)
    Next
    Erase tmpArr
    GetBetween=result
End Function

Function ReplaceWholeWord(ByVal strText, strWord, strToReplaceWith)
    ReplaceWholeWord = strText
    If InStr(strText, strWord)<1 Then Exit Function

    'Text is only the word?
    If strText=strWord Then
        strText = Replace(strText, strWord, strToReplaceWith)
    Else  
        'Text starting with word?
        If InStr(strText, strWord & " ")=1 Then
            strText = strToReplaceWith & " " & Right(strText, Len(strText) - Len(strWord & " "))
        End If

        'Text ends with word?
        If Right(strText, Len(" " & strWord))=(" " & strWord) Then
            strText = Left(strText, Len(strText) - Len(" " & strWord)) & " " & strToReplaceWith
        End If

        'Text ends with word and a period?
        If Right(strText, Len(" " & strWord & "."))=(" " & strWord & ".") Then
            strText = Left(strText, Len(strText) - Len(" " & strWord & ".")) & " " & strToReplaceWith & "."
        End If

        'Replace between other words:
        strText = Replace(strText, " " & strWord & " ", " " & strToReplaceWith & " ")
    End If

    ReplaceWholeWord = strText
End Function
```

With those functions, here is sample code that replace keywords the way you want:

```vbs
Const KEYWORD = "keyword"
Dim strHTML, arrTagsToFind, x
Dim curItemsArray,  y, curItem
Dim curReplacedItem
arrTagsToFind = Array("p", "div")
strHTML = "<b>this keyword will not be replaced</b><p>Some text with the keyword.</p>keyword here won't be replaced too<p>Some other text with the keyword22 that is not whole word but end with keyword</p><div>keyword first</div>"
For x=0 To UBound(arrTagsToFind)
    curItemsArray = GetBetween(strHTML, "<" + arrTagsToFind(x) + ">", "</" + arrTagsToFind(x) + ">")
    For y=0 To UBound(curItemsArray)
        curItem = curItemsArray(y)
        curReplacedItem = ReplaceWholeWord(curItem, KEYWORD, "<a href=""#foo"">" & KEYWORD & "</a>")
        strHTML = Replace(strHTML, curItem, curReplacedItem)
    Next
Next
Response.Write(strHTML)
```